# Dropdown Button within a form

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement a dropdown button in a bootstrap form. Unfortunately, the form is not submitted. It looks like that:

```
<form class="form-inline" method="post" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text"></input>
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <a class="btn dropdown-toggle pull-right" data-toggle="dropdown" href="">
                Show <span class=caret></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><input name="_show" class='btn' type="submit" value="Show"></input></li>
                <li><input name="_export" class='btn' type="submit" value="Export"></input></li>
            </ul>
            <button name="_export" class='btn' type="submit">Export</button>        
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Two questions:

1. The submit button outside the 'div' container works, the both inputs within do nothing. Why?
2. The dropdown button is not aligned properly, why that?

*** EDIT ***

1. If the buttons are removed from the ul, there is a small empty list which appears when clicking the 'show button'
   The same name attribute does not really matter because the both buttons do the same, the one outside the btn-group shall be removed. as soon as the one within works properly

A very strange thing is, if i put

```
    <div class="btn-group" style="vertical-align: middle" data-toggle="dropdown">
  <a class="btn dropdown-toggle pull-right" data-toggle="dropdown" href="">
    Show <span class=caret></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="/hello">Interactive</a></li>
      <li><a href="/hello2">Pic</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Nothing happens when clicking on the dropdown-menu entries. on the buttom in firefox, i can see that there is a link, but a click does not have any effect...

1. Alignment: I found out, there is a general problem with twitter bootstrap button-group whidh is solved by:
   style="vertical-align: middle"

Comment: `action=""` supposed to be empty?

Comment: Yes, the form is to be submitted to the same url, there is a validator in the backend

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is: instead of having two buttons 'show' and 'export' having a dropdown button with the two choices

Comment: 1. Assuming that when you say both inputs within the div 'do nothing' that literally nothing happens when you click it. What happens when those buttons are removed from the ul? - Also you have 2 buttons with the same name attribute, is that not conflicting in your back-end validator?

2. You need to provide more information about what is wrong with the alignment, without an example or an image, we can't exactly help

Comment: `<input></input>`? It's a selfclosing tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code :

```
<div class="container row-fluid">
  <form method="post" class="form-horizontal " action="">
    <fieldset>
      <input type="text" name="tex"/>
      <button name="_export" class='btn' type="submit">Export</button>   
      <span class="dropdown">
        <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" id="dLabel" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">
          <i class="icon-minus-sign"></i> Anmeld annonce
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
          <li><a name="_show" href="#">Hello</a></li>
          <li><a name="_export" href="#">Boy</a></li>
        </ul>
      </span>
    </fieldset>    
  </form>
</div>
```

MartialE

Comment: That's it, could you also please explain, why all this works with your construct (within a span) and does not work within a div?

Comment: Very simple : <SPAN> is an element **inline**, & <DIV> is an element **bloc**. In your case you want a dropdown **inline** so use i use <span>, ok ?

Comment: Yes, but i always thought it only makes difference for style.
I replaced your '<a name="_show" href="#">Hello</a>' by a submit input.
<input name="_show" type="submit" value="" class="text">

Now the form is submitted. But why would n t it be submitted in a block element?